# Save and load xmpp messages in core data

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data

I am making chat app and I want to save to core data user profile(images, name, age, detail info) and this talks with other users.  In need save all new messages, I need that I can see that messages was read, also if user will want to see his history I will load it from web serves (like scrolling to top of VC).

I use that code to save and load messages, but how can I use my results array for construction chat history for 2 exact users?

```
//this code in XMPPStream
 xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc]init];
[xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
 xmppStream.autoStartTLS = YES;

 xmppReconnect = [[XMPPReconnect alloc]init];
[xmppReconnect activate:self.xmppStream];

 xmppMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage = [XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
 xmppMessageArchivingModule = [[XMPPMessageArchiving alloc]initWithMessageArchivingStorage:xmppMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage];
[xmppMessageArchivingModule setClientSideMessageArchivingOnly:YES];
[xmppMessageArchivingModule activate:xmppStream];    //By this line all your messages are stored in CoreData
[xmppMessageArchivingModule addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

To retrieve the saved message in talks VC

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.xmppMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage mainThreadManagedObjectContext];
 NSEntityDescription *messageEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject" inManagedObjectContext:context];

 fetchRequest.entity = messageEntity;

 NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"timestamp" ascending:NO];
 fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
 NSError *error = nil;
 NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
//Now I get the NSArray with element type of "XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject"
```

Comment: Show us some code :) What examples have you tried ?

Comment: @marcio, I update my post, I need that results array will be with messages, dates, images, users name for 2 users that start chatting, but it is not

Comment: So you have created your data model? Added entities? Process the downloaded data and save into the data store? The fetch requests return results? How far are you, be more specific about what doesn't work.

Comment: @Wain, I think I just add this code, I download data and I receive it in results array, but I have the same data for any 2 chatting users.

Comment: I do not know how can I use that array for construction  chat history for 2 exact users

Answer (score 0):

if someone still needs an answer:

just add this predicate to your request.

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bareJidStr = %@", user.jid];
```